# Cumulative filters in Spring Security 3

Tags: java, spring-security, servlet-filters

I need to secure my website using 2 layers. First is an LDAP check, next is a username/password entry. I have written both custom authentication filters for both checks.

If the LDAP filter fails the user should be redirected to an 'access denied' page, and if the username/password failed the user should be redirected back to the login page.

How can I set up these filters in my config.xml file? Here is what I have currently

```
<sec:http entry-point-ref="loginAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="isAnonymous()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/*"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_LDAP') and hasRole('ROLE_CRESTA')" />

    <sec:custom-filter ref="ldapAuthenticationFilter"
        before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="usernameAuthenticationFilter"
        position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
</sec:http>
```

with

```
public class LdapAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
```

and

```
public class CrestaUsernameAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
```

My current thinking is for each filter to add one of the required roles, but when the LDAP filter doesn't add both roles I am immediately denied access.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that approach will not work because as soon as your LDAP filter returns successfully, Spring Security considers the user has been completely authenticated and skips the username/password filter.

In your situation I would use the standard form login security, customizing just my UserDetailsService so that instead of going just to Cresta to create the UserDetails instance, it would query your LDAP server too for user roles.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I've ended up doing